# what's the purpose of leading colon in key map?

Tags: key-bindings

```
:imap mmm <Esc>
vmap '=y :w !pbcopy<CR><CR>
```

I copied two lines of vim map scripts. The first one has a leading colon while the latter one doesn't have.

So, what's the purpose of the leading colon?

Answer (score 3):

The colons don’t do anything.

The same commands can be typed into Vim interactively, in which case you need the colon to switch from normal mode to command-line mode.

When executing Vimscript from a file, the colons are not necessary, so it’s usual to omit them, but if they are included the commands will still work.